# Show that $|a-b|<\frac{|b|}{2}$ implies $\frac{|b|}{2}<|a|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Pretty simple, for $a,b \in \mathbb R$, show that $|a-b|<\frac{|b|}{2}$ implies $\frac{|b|}{2}<|a|$.  I can see this graphically on the number line, but I can't seem to show it algebraically.

I'm think it involves the triangle inequalities:

> $$|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$$
>
> $$|x-y|\ge||x|-|y||.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rewrite $|a-b|<\cfrac{|b|}{2}$ as $|b-a|<\cfrac{|b|}{2}$.

Now, I'll use your second version of the triangle inequality (without the extra bars) and we obtain
$$|b|-|a| \leq |b-a|<\frac{|b|}{2}$$
which means
$$|b|-|a| < \frac{|b|}{2}$$
Finally, add $|a|$ and substract $|b|/2$ to both sides of the latter to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|a-b|<|b|/2,$ we know that $$-|b|/2<a-b<|b|/2,$$ or $$b-|b|/2<a<b+|b|/2,$$ from the definition of the absolute value. Try to consider what happens if you choose $b$ to have different signs (if $b\geq 0,$ look at what happens to the first $<$, and if $b<0,$ do the same for the second $<$).

Answer (score -1):

$$ |a-b|<\frac {|b|}{2} \implies -\frac {|b|}{2} < a-b<\frac {|b|}{2}$$

$$\implies b-\frac {|b|}{2} <a< b+\frac {|b|}{2}$$

For $b>0$ we get $$\frac {b}{2} <a<\frac {3b}{2}\implies \frac {b}{2} <a $$
for $b<0$  we get $$\frac {3b}{2} <a<\frac {b}{2}\implies -\frac {b}{2} <- a$$
 Thus  in any  case  we have $$\frac {|b|}{2}< |a|$$